# how to avoid repeat the condition many times by if statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, logic

Is there a better way to avoid repeating the condition many times by if statement?

```
 for entity in entities:
        if (entity.entity_id.startswith('sensor') and  "sourcenodeid" not in entity.entity_id and "interval" not in entity.entity_id and "previous"  not in entity.entity_id and "exporting" not in entity.entity_id and "management" not in entity.entity_id and "yr" not in entity.entity_id and "alarm" not in entity.entity_id ):
            data = remote.get_state(api, entity.entity_id)
            #print(data)
```

I tried with `or` but it doesn't work properly because I got entity with condition which should not be stored in data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator expression with `all`.

```
if entity.entity_id.startswith('sensor') and all(elem not in entity.entity_id for elem in ("sourcenodeid", "interval", "previous", "exporting", "management", "yr", "alarm")):
```

Comment: Thank you. the  generator expression with all is better than reapet it everytime

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in `all`:

```
tup = ("sourcenodeid", "interval", "previous", "exporting", "management" , "yr", "alarm")
for entity in entities:
    if entity.entity_id.startswith('sensor') and \
       all(x not in entity.entity_id for x in tup)):
        data = remote.get_state(api, entity.entity_id)
```

Comment: It is pretty the same solution of @Daniel. The difference is only that you define tupel before. that makes the program more understandable.